# Association [values] was not found upon using Simple.OData.Client

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, simple.odata.client

I have an OData service configured via an *IModelConfiguration*

```
public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion)
{
     builder.EntitySet<ValuesContainer>("ValuesContainer");
     builder.AddComplexType(typeof(ValueItem));
}
```

Which produces the following (obfuscated and selected the relevant parts) metadata:

```
<Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="MyProject.Api.Models">
            <EntityType Name="ValuesContainer">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="values" Type="Collection(MyProject.Api.Models.ValueItem)" />
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <ComplexType Name="ValueItem">
                <Property Name="value" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
            </ComplexType>
        </Schema>
   </DataServices>
</Edmx>
```

Basically I have an entity type *ValuesContainer* which has a collection of a complex type *ValueItem*.

Following example works fine when I try to query the service via http get:

*~/odata/valuescontainer?$filter=values/any(v:v/value eq 'example')*

This example gives me any *ValuesContainer* which has a value containing example.

Yet, when I use *Simple.OData.Client* in another C# application, I get the error *Simple.OData.Client.UnresolvableObjectException: 'Association [values] not found'*

Code of my Simple.OData.Client:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var odataClientSettings = new ODataClientSettings(httpClient)
{
    BaseUri = new Uri($"{_myEndPointConfig.BaseUrl}/odata/")
};
var entries = await new ODataClient(odataClientSettings).For<ValuesContainer>("ValuesContainer")
                .Filter(x => x.Values.Any(v => v.value == "example").FindEntriesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I tried to trace it down via Fiddler whether the request was bad, but it happens somewhere between receiving the metadata of the OData service and processing the expression.

I noticed it throws an exception at following location

```
namespace Simple.OData.Client.V4.Adapter
{
    public class Metadata : MetadataBase {
    ...
        private IEdmNavigationProperty GetNavigationProperty(string collectionName, string propertyName)
        {
            var property = GetEntityType(collectionName).NavigationProperties()
                .BestMatch(x => x.Name, propertyName, NameMatchResolver);

            if (property == null)
                // obviously being thrown here
                throw new UnresolvableObjectException(propertyName, $"Association [{propertyName}] not found");

            return property;
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

It's trying to get my property *Values* as a *NavigationProperty*, but it isn't one.

Is my metadata and thus configuration of my OData service wrong and why is it working via a http get call, or is this misbehaviour of Simple.OData.Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in Simple.OData.Client which demands collections to have a *NavigationProperty*, which is not correct.

https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/issues/274